# Deactivate VS warning "Macro in skipped region"

Tags: unreal-4, visual-studio

Since the UE4 API relies heavily on macros outside of function bodies, the **IntelliSense** function (not the compiler!) of Visual Studio 2017 throws a lot of warnings with update 15.7, also visible in the scroll area.

[image: Intellisense warning]

Is there a possibility in the Visual Studio settings to deactivate such kind of warnings?

---

The option to deactivate IntelliSense

- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable IntelliSense

will disable those warnings. However I don't want to renounce IntelliSense completely. Maybe Visual Studio offers more fine grain control over IntelliSense via its GUI or some settings file to disable only those macro warnings?

---

EDIT: The [Visual Studio team recommends](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/248016/green-squiggles-and-light-bulb-with-macro-in-skipp.html) using a *.hint* file to register macros as workaround. However maintaining a separate macro list is not the way to go. You can also vote there that the VS Team works on that.

Comment: What is the full text of the warning from the output window? Is there a warning number associated with it?

Comment: @JoshPetrie No, it is not the compiler, it is only IntelliSense. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Workaround

Bit of a hacky workaround, but try this for now:

1. Add a **cpp.hint** to your root folder
2. Add the missing defines in here, for example, mine is:

   ```
   #define UCLASS()
   #define GENERATED_BODY()
   #define UFUNCTION()
   ```
3. Restart visual studio and give it a few seconds. This should get rid of your green squiggles.
4. List item

---

### Microsoft's Hint File Docs

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997977.aspx

---

### Similar Question in Epic's Forums

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/787769/visual-studio-editor-saying-macro-in-skipped-regio.html

Comment: RE: maintaining a separate macro file isn't the way to go -- There's really nothing to lose by adding this hint file, you can simply add it to your respective version control ignore list and it will serve as a simple configuration file for the compiler. Ideal? No, but what's worse... adding a simple config, or meaningless squiggles?